Handling Python Type Checker Errors with Return Type Declarations (fields default values = None)
I'm encountering an issue with my Python code using Pyright type checker, specifically when I try to remove Any from the return type declaration.
Error message:
Function with declared return type "int" must return value on all code paths. "None" is incompatible with "int".

Now every single path returns an int at some point, is this a bug or I just have to use the Union thing as a python thing.
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any, Union, List

@dataclass
class IntOrString:
    I: Union[int, None] = None
    S: Union[str, None] = None

def funny_sum(xs: List[IntOrString]) -> int | Any:
    if not xs:
        return 0
    
    head, *tail = xs

    match head:
        case IntOrString(I=i) if i is not None:
            return i + funny_sum(tail)
        case IntOrString(S=s) if s is not None:
            return len(s) + funny_sum(tail)

xs: List[IntOrString] = [IntOrString(I=1), IntOrString(S="hello"), IntOrString(I=3), IntOrString(S="world")]
# Output will be 1 + 5 + 3 + 5 = 14
result = funny_sum(xs)

Error
def funny_sum(xs: List[IntOrString]) -> int: { ... }

In Swift, enums support pattern matching, and this code would work fine. Does this mean that data classes in Python do not support pattern matching?
I appreciate any advice on resolving this issue with the return type declaration in Python.
Edit:
Refer to this question for a similar approach that results in the same error: Handling Python Type Checker Errors with Return Type Declarations.

If I change it from int | Any to int | None addition would not work, I get this error: Operator "+" not supported for types "int" and "int | None"
Operator "+" not supported for types "int" and "None" when expected type is "int | None"

The premise of the question is not true: Not every single path returns an int, if no case matches in match head the function returns None.

@mkrieger1 assume list is of type list[IntOrString], I will edit the question to be more clear. So in this case you are not allowed to pass other things not defined in this code.

You can try adding a default case in match or a default return statement at the end of function.

The reason the type checker warns about the function possibly returning None is because not all patterns are exhausted.
If only (exactly) 1 of the fields of head is None, then one of the cases is bound to be matched. However, what happend if both I and S are None?
In that case, non of the cases will match and the function will return None.
Since Python's dataclass doesn't allow defining mutually exclusive types, you have 2 options with this.
Either add a default case which should throw an error or you can change the IntOrString to have a single field of type str | int.
Option 1 - Adding a default case
def funny_sum(xs: List[IntOrString]) -> int | Any:
    if not xs:
        return 0
    
    head, *tail = xs

    match head:
        case IntOrString(I=i) if i is not None:
            return i + funny_sum(tail)
        case IntOrString(S=s) if s is not None:
            return len(s) + funny_sum(tail)
        case _:
            raise ValueError("Either I or S must be set!")

xs: List[IntOrString] = [IntOrString(I=1), IntOrString(S="hello"), IntOrString(I=3), IntOrString(S="world")]
# Output will be 1 + 5 + 3 + 5 = 14
result = funny_sum(xs)

Option 2 - Modifying the IntOrString type
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any, Union, List

@dataclass
class IntOrString:
    V: Union[int, str]

def funny_sum(xs: List[IntOrString]) -> int | Any:
    if not xs:
        return 0
    
    head, *tail = xs

    match head.V:
        case int() as i:
            return i + funny_sum(tail)
        case str() as s:
            return len(s) + funny_sum(tail)

xs: List[IntOrString] = [IntOrString(V=1), IntOrString(V="hello"), IntOrString(V=3), IntOrString(V="world")]
# Output will be 1 + 5 + 3 + 5 = 14
result = funny_sum(xs)

Option 3 - Forcing the type checker
You can force the type-checker to ignore the inferred type and instead use the type you tell it.
def funny_sum(xs: List[IntOrString]) -> int:  # pyright: ignore
    ...


so it was the class implementation, I and S = None, idk why I was focusing on the argument types. So to only allow one property/field at a time I had to give a default value. I was thinking that somehow python takes care of that by default.
